# correct syntax for placing javascript function into other function

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have this code that is a couple of little animations.

```
function circle_progess() {
  var divElement = $('div'); //log all div elements
  if (retina()) {
    $(".whiteCircle").knob({
      'min': 0,
      'max': 100,
      'readOnly': true,
      'width': 240,
      'height': 240,
      'bgColor': 'rgba(255,255,255,0.5)',
      'fgColor': 'rgba(255,255,255,0.9)',
      'dynamicDraw': true,
      'thickness': 0.1,
      'tickColorizeValues': true
    });

    $(".circleStat").css('zoom', 0.5);
    $(".whiteCircle").css('zoom', 0.999);
  } else {

    $(".whiteCircle").knob({
      'min': 0,
      'max': 100,
      'readOnly': true,
      'width': 120,
      'height': 120,
      'bgColor': 'rgba(255,255,255,0.5)',
      'fgColor': 'rgba(255,255,255,0.9)',
      'dynamicDraw': true,
      'thickness': 0.1,
      'tickColorizeValues': true
    });
  }

  $(".circleStatsItemBox").each(function() {
    var value = $(this).find(".count > .number").html();
    var unit = $(this).find(".value > .unit").html();
    var percent = $(this).find("input").val() / 100;

    countSpeed = 2300 * percent;
    endValue = value;

    $(this).find(".count > .unit").html(unit);
    $(this).find(".count > .number").countTo({
      from: 0,
      to: endValue,
      speed: countSpeed,
      refreshInterval: 50
    });

    //$(this).find(".count").html(value*percent + unit);
  });
}
```

i want to replace the below code line that gives an alert when scrolled with the above code.  so i execute function on scroll.  I cant seem to integrate the code, can someone help me out ?

```
var $findme = $('.whiteCircle');

function Scrolled() {
  $findme.each(function() {
    var $section = $(this),
      findmeOffset = $section.offset(),
      findmeTop = findmeOffset.top,
      findmeBottom = $section.height() + findmeTop,
      scrollTop = $(document).scrollTop(),
      visibleBottom = window.innerHeight,
      prevVisible = $section.prop('_visible');

    if ((findmeTop > scrollTop + visibleBottom) ||
      findmeBottom < scrollTop) {
      visible = false;
    } else visible = true;

    if (!prevVisible && visible) {
      alert($section.text());
    }
    $section.prop('_visible', visible);
  });

}

function Setup() {
  var $top = $('#top'),
    $bottom = $('#bottom');

  $top.height(500);
  $bottom.height(500);

  $(window).scroll(function() {
    Scrolled();
  });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  Setup();

});
```

SIMPLY PUT I want this....

```
var $findme = $('circle_progress');

function Scrolled() {
    $findme.each(function() {
          var $section = $(this),
            findmeOffset = $section.offset(),
            findmeTop = findmeOffset.top,
            findmeBottom = $section.height() + findmeTop,
            scrollTop = $(document).scrollTop(),
            visibleBottom = window.innerHeight,
            prevVisible = $section.prop('_visible');

          if ((findmeTop > scrollTop + visibleBottom) ||
            findmeBottom < scrollTop) {
            visible = false;
          } else visible = true;

          if (!prevVisible && visible) {


            function circle_progess() {

              var divElement = $('div'); //log all div elements

              if (retina()) {

                $(".whiteCircle").knob({
                  'min': 0,
                  'max': 100,
                  'readOnly': true,
                  'width': 240,
                  'height': 240,
                  'bgColor': 'rgba(255,255,255,0.5)',
                  'fgColor': 'rgba(255,255,255,0.9)',
                  'dynamicDraw': true,
                  'thickness': 0.1,
                  'tickColorizeValues': true
                });

                $(".circleStat").css('zoom', 0.5);
                $(".whiteCircle").css('zoom', 0.999);


              } else {

                $(".whiteCircle").knob({
                  'min': 0,
                  'max': 100,
                  'readOnly': true,
                  'width': 120,
                  'height': 120,
                  'bgColor': 'rgba(255,255,255,0.5)',
                  'fgColor': 'rgba(255,255,255,0.9)',
                  'dynamicDraw': true,
                  'thickness': 0.1,
                  'tickColorizeValues': true
                });

              }



              $(".circleStatsItemBox").each(function() {
                var value = $(this).find(".count > .number").html();
                var unit = $(this).find(".value > .unit").html();
                var percent = $(this).find("input").val() / 100;

                countSpeed = 2300 * percent;
                endValue = value;

                $(this).find(".count > .unit").html(unit);
                $(this).find(".count > .number").countTo({
                  from: 0,
                  to: endValue,
                  speed: countSpeed,
                  refreshInterval: 50
                });

                //$(this).find(".count").html(value*percent + unit);
              });

            }
```

html added to give some clarity on how output might look....

```
<div class="circleStatsItemBox blue">
<div class="header">Levels of Involvement</div>
<span class="percent">% Increase</span>
<div class="circleStat"> <input value="20" class="whiteCircle" type="text"> </div>
<div class="footer"><span class="count"> <span class="number">40</span> <span>Before</span>
</span> <span class="sep"> / </span> <span class="value"> <span class="number">50</span><span class="unit"> During</span></span> </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't see where you are calling circle_progress? If the function is not called then it cannot run. My suggestion would be to put in console.logs or alerts in some key places to see where it breaks.

Comment: have edited the code to show what i am trying to do .

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to put the function definition inside the other code. Just leave it outside and write:

```
if (!prevVisible && visible) {
    circle_progress();
}
```

Comment: that makes sense to me but it didn't work, replaced the alert text with the function as you describe ? hmm

Comment: What is it supposed to do, what did it do instead? Any errors in the JS console? I have no idea what `.knob()` is, it's not a standard jQuery method.

Comment: its basicaly a donut chart that animates the percentage value ... i will put the html in the edit of one of the charts there are many of them but want to start their associated function only when they come into the viewscreen , edited now

Comment: p.s i appreciate your help

Comment: ...clearly instead of .section it needs to be .circleStat  ... i think

Comment: If calling `circle_progress()` works from other places, I don't know why it wouldn't work when you call it from here.

Comment: ahhh i think i need to declare .circlestat which has a input value as 0 if not visible otherwise it will just present static value and not show animation ?

Comment: can i just email it to you , im not sure what i am doing wrong /

Comment: One issue with this is that you might call `circle_progress()` multiple times, since you're calling it from the `.each()` loop. That probably won't work. What is it supposed to do in that case?

Comment: WHOOOOA ..... i found this code at the top of the js file ....   if(jQuery.browser.version.substring(0, 2) == "8.") {
   
  //disable jQuery Knob
  
 } else {
  
  circle_progess();
  
 }

Comment: i dont even know what that means

Comment: I think it's checking if it's running IE8.

Comment: so i would have to run this in ie8 to make our code work ?... how would i take that out ?

Comment: in the debug it says circle_progress is not defined

Comment: If you're in IE8, it doesn't run `circle_progress()`. It's just a simple `if/else` statement.

Comment: If you're getting that error, you may have messed up the variable scope.

Comment: i made a jfiddle .... it doesnt work on run though https://jsfiddle.net/greggy_coding/hafs3us5/

Comment: You haven't loaded the `cleditor` plugin, so `$('.cleditor').cleditor();` gets an error. Try removing all the stuff that isn't relevant to this question. You also need to load the plugin that defines `knob()`.

Comment: have added cleditor  , knob and got rid of other stuff still not working

Comment: `jQuery.browser` was removed in jQuery 1.9. Get rid of everything that uses it.